# JavaScript - JSON loading by dynamical value

Tags: javascript, json

I want to load the following JSON-structure seen in this function.

```
       function load1(input) {
            var txt = '{ "kind1" : [{ "name":"blue" , "color":"blue" },{ "name":"red" , "color":"red" },{ "name":"yellow" , "color":"yellow" } ], "kind2" : [{ "name":"blue2" , "color":"blue2" },{ "name":"red2" , "color":"red2" },{ "name":"yellow2" , "color":"yellow2" } ]}';
            var obj = eval("(" + txt + ")");
            var output = "";

            for (var i in obj.kind1) {
                output += obj.kind1[i].name + ", " + obj.kind1[i].color + "<br>"
            }
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = output + "Eingabe: " + input
        }
```

Now I need the function loading JSON dynamically by the "id" of the link.

```
<a onclick="return load1(this.id)" id="kind1">link_product1</a>
<a onclick="return load2(this.id)" id="kind2">link_product2</a>
```

Is it possible to change the query "obj.kind1" to do this? I can load the id into function, but replacing "kind1" with "input" is not working. Anybody can show how this logic would work?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're executing `eval` instead of `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Im using function getJSON in my project. This is just for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `txt` hard coded in your function body, it seems to me that you could just hard code the actual JavaScript objects you want to work with and skip the `eval` step.  If there's some reason you don't want to do this, you should use `JSON.parse` instead.  It is supported even by relatively old browsers (IE8).

Then, you can access the provided key with bracket notation:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj[input].length; i++) {
    output += obj[input][i].name //etc.
```

EDIT: based on your "Im using function getJSON," this seems to say that you are using jQuery and `$.parseJSON` is available instead.  The data returned to the `getJSON` callback *does not need to be parsed*.  It should already be JavaScript constructs.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Im not so confirm to javascript. But your right. Im using jquery and im not parsing the values in my project.